# Can you launch a application page from a background task in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a periodic task, how can i launch a page from the period task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodic tasks do not have the capability to launch or interact with any UI elements.